# Two column layout

Tags: html, css

Here is what I'm trying to do.

I have two columns. Let's call them `col1` and `col2`. I want it so that if the height of `col2` increases, the height of `col1` will increase accordingly to the same height. How can I achieve this?

I know that I can do it using tables, but I'm looking for a css-based solutions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+equal+height

Comment: Also do you have an example of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of tutorials on Google:

http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=same+height+columns

Other stuff here:

[Equal height columns in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378314/equal-height-columns-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

As [CSS - Equal Height Columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114757/css-equal-height-columns) already explains the best resource probably is http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-multi-column-liquid-layouts

Basically you have wrappers around your columns and they become your actual backgrounds and not the columns themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can fake it with an image using the faux columns technique, but you can do it just with CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/s8uLG/3/

You set your container up with overflow set to hidden, then on each div add negative margin-bottom and equal positive padding-bottom.

```
#container { overflow: hidden; }
#container div { float: left; background: #ccc; width: 200px; margin-bottom: -2000px; padding-bottom: 2000px; }
#container .col2 { background: #eee; }

<div id="container">
   <div>
        <p>Content 1</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col2">
        <p>Content 2</p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** If you want a border round it then have a look at this example - http://www.ejeliot.com/samples/equal-height-columns/example-6.html